# Tar ignores compression level, what to do?

Tags: linux, tar

Im using the following command(s):

```
GZIP=-9 tar -cf test9 directory
GZIP=-5 tar -cf test5 directory
GZIP=-2 tar -cf test2 directory
```

all test* result is the same, looks like compression level was ignored. How to get it into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the 'z' option to enable gzip compression, which then gave me the warning "gzip: warning: GZIP environment variable is deprecated; use an alias or script" with GZIP environment variable set.

I would use this syntax:

```
tar cf - directory | gzip -9 > test9.tar.gz
```

and just learned that you can also do:

```
tar cf test9 -I 'gzip -9' directory
``
```

Comment: both works well, but -I 'gzip' is the most compact!

Comment: It only looked that way because I used a .tar.gz suffix (out of habit) on the pipe version initially.  It's only 1 byte longer now, and could be 1 byte smaller if you remove the spaces around the pipe symbol.

Answer (score 2):

TAR is file format that alignes content of files in a single chunk to increase dictionary and, as a result, decrease result archive size. You have to add `-z` option to compress resulting archive with **gzip**.